# Active Directory: LVR not enabled after rising FFL to Windows 2003

Tags: windows, active-directory

I raised the Forest Function Level to Windows 2003 on a Windows 2003 DC 
But when running repadmin/bind I see the LVR is not enabled:

```
Linked Value Replication is set to NO
```

Do you have any suggestion or fix?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some details of the number of dcs in the forest? Did you check this against a DC that had realised the FFL had been increased as it is possible it hadnt yet replicated inbound?

Use ldp.exe to connect to the DC. Check the rootdse information on the right side pane of ldp to see if it returned forestfunctionality at version 2. I would then check with repadmin again. Please make sure you are using the latest version of the binary (although I have not yet come across a repadmin.exe that didnt report this back correctly).

I would also modify a group membership and dump the metadata (repadmin /showobjmeta). It should report the version for the member attribute (assuming the group was modified before FFL) and also version of each value inside member that you've added/removed to the group since the FFL increase with the type PRESENT/ABSENT based on whether the member was added/removed.